# Swift - Cannot change UICollectionViewFlowLayout dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

On `viewDidLoad` I set a `collectionViewLayout` for a `UICollectionViewCell` with a `UILabel` saying "loading content...", when the apps fetchs the content from a server, it does something like this:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
...
// some configuration for the layout

// here it crash:
collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
```

It crash with saying this message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x24479b0b 0x23c36dff 0x2438a6d3 0x29275999 0x29271d13 0x29272aaf 0x28be537f 0x28be4667 0x1778dc 0x165f48 0x1661b8 0x16e774 0x16f038 0xf950c 0xf9174 0xdefb0 0xe1934 0xdf98c 0x52ed78 0x52d700 0x52bfc8 0x4df9c0 0x1531ba7 0x1531b93 0x1536659 0x2443b755 0x24439c4f 0x243881c9 0x24387fbd 0x259a4af9 0x28ac0435 0x131254 0x24034873)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

The things I did is set one `collectionViewLayout` replace that with another.

I tried to invalidate the layout with `invalidateLayout()` reloading or not reloading the `collectionView` before to replace the `collectionViewLayout` and it stills crashing.

What can I do to change the `collectionViewLayout` dynamically? or What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding an exception breakpoint, it may help pinpoint your issue - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: As to the issue itself - check places in your code when you access arrays and make sure that there is actually something in them. The exception says it all right there.

Comment: @Losiowaty I think the array is not the problem because if I don't try to replace the `collectionViewLayout` it works perfectly

Comment: @Losiowaty I add an exception breakpoint and it stops on `collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)`

Comment: Ok, can you post more code? Especially parts with handling the network reaponse, the whole method with the lines you already posted and `cellForItem...` method. Or even the whole controller class if it isn't too big ;)

Comment: @Losiowaty I found a solution implementing `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, I guess I'm going to use that delegate instead to replace the entire layout object.

Answer (score 6):

I hit the same issue for iOS9 and iOS8.

In my case, call `collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()` after `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` to solve.